# How should I protect mass-assignment in Sinatra app with Datamapper?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mass-assignment, ruby-datamapper, attr-accessible

I have `Link` model in Sinatra app

```
class Link
  include DataMapper::Resource
  has n, :views

  validates_presence_of :url,
    message: "You must specify a URL."
  validates_length_of   :url,
    maximum: 4096,
    allow_blank: true,
    message: "That URL is too long."
  validates_format_of :url,
    with: %r{^(https?|ftp)://.+}i,
    allow_blank: true,
    message: "The URL must start with http://, https://, or ftp:// ."

  property :id,         Serial
  property :url,        String
  property :token,      String
  property :created_at, DateTime
end
```

How to set up something like `attr_accessible :url, :token`?

Comment: Here's a way: http://kellishaver.tumblr.com/post/15802062803/mass-assignment-protection-datamapper-and-sinatra

Comment: @regedarek I suppose you mean `attr_accessible` instead of `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `DataMapper::MassAssignmentSecurity` module from the gem `dm-rails`.

```
class Link

  include DataMapper::Resource
  include DataMapper::MassAssignmentSecurity
  attr_accessible :url, :token

  # ...

end
```